# Question about medical device

Tags: translation

What is the common name of the device shown below?

I know that it's a device used in spine or back related problems. I need a name for main part (that thick stripe on the bottom) and that Y-shaped part placed along the spine.

[image]

Comment: Beim Motorradfahren würde man den breiten Gurt Nierengurt nennen. "Vertikales, Y-förmiges Teil der Rückenbandage" für den anderen Teil würde ich sagen, aber vielleicht gibt es auch mediizinische Fachausdrücke.

Comment: How is it called in English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Die Bandage. Auf dem Bild ist eine Rückenbandage.

Answer (score 5):

The German name for the orthotics in the picture is

[Orthese (Stützkorsett)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthese)